# My Kubernetes service is running on HTTPS, I wanted to expose it over Istio ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, apache-nifi, istio

I deployed NIFI using cetic helm charts in GKE, its service is working on HTTPS.
now I don't want to make it as a load balancer, I'm using Istio ingress gateway for to expose it on my DNS name.
I used Istio for http service, but not I'm confused about the HTTPS.

Please help me on this

Comment: Please provide more details of your query over mTLS in istio which you are looking for?

Comment: My service is working on 8443 port, I want to use istio here to exose the service with my dns name

Comment: Please refer istio secure gateway documentation how to enable the the gateway with mTLS.  To start with you can use tls: mode: Simple along with secret having the certificates. Along with PeerAuthentication, DestinationRule.  This will enable the mTLS communication.  https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/

Comment: Thanks, for your reply I followed the blog which you shared, but the thing is NIFI is not working with GCP managed ingress, so we used Nginx ingress, and my issue got resolved. The problem is with NIFI only I think its not supporting istio